# file_put_contents create file with wrong timestamp

Tags: php, date, time, timezone

I am having an issue with "file_put_contents" when i run this code:

```
file_put_contents("/var/www/html/storage/views/temp", "helllo world");
```

It saves the file with a time 1hr in the future. 
So where dose it get the time?

I have set php.ini  date.timezone = "Europe/London" (as per system timezone) and that seems not to help

Comment: `timezone` in php does not have anything to do with machine time. You file time is based on system time.

Comment: probably we are on BST and you have set GMT

Comment: got it known bug in winscp http://winscp.net/forum/viewtopic.php?t=3057

Answer (score 1):

`php.ini` `date.timezone` option specifies which timezone PHP will use internally.

Most Unix/Linux system use UTC as **hardware** and then set the **system** clock to a given timezone.

You end-up with three different timezone, but it should be totally transparent.

Your problem may be due by the fact that your **system** timezone is different than your **php** timezone.

To check your **system** timezone, you can do `date +%Z`

Depending on your need you will either have to change your PHP timezone according to your system timezone, or convert the date of your timestamp to manage your file.

Excepting you've a good reason to do it, I suggest to adjust your php timezone with your system timezone.

Comment: ok date +%Z returns BST so i ran "TZ='Europe/London'; export TZ" and re ran date +%Z got BST

Comment: also note that <?php echo date() ?> gives correct time. so if i 'file_put_contents("/var/www/html/storage/views/temp", date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A'));' writes correct time to file but file created time is 1hr future

Comment: As I said, the PHP date has nothing to do with the system date. Concerning your timezone change try, you can't change timezone like this, you can take a look there: http://www.wikihow.com/Change-the-Timezone-in-Linux to know how to do.

Comment: done that no change... :( but have noted that putty reports a different time from winscp..

Comment: I suspect that downloading the file either modify the timestamp and/or cast the timezone to your desktop timezone. Try locally on the server instead. Note that if you're running a VPS you may not be able to change the hw clock.

Answer (score 0):

file_put_contents gives the file the **server** time. That means, when looking at the timestamp of the file, the *timezone of the server* must be taken into account and must eventually be transformed to the *timezone of the client*.

On my linux machine date outputs: `Thu Sep 20 11:23:28 CEST 2012` and thats the timestamp for the file also. When in CST timezone, you have to substract 7 hours from the the timestamp to get the creation time in CST.

Comment: I'd rather avoid manually conversion on date as it may result in a mess, best bet is to use native php function for that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle the timestamp value correctly, when you use it. Examine this:

```
<?php
$file = __DIR__ . '/test.dat';
file_put_contents($file, "hello world");
print(gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:s T', filectime($file)) . "\n");
print(date('Y-m-d H:i:s T', filectime($file)) . "\n");
```

Output:

```
2012-09-20 09:29:17 GMT 
2012-09-20 11:29:17 CEST
```

Depending on the specific date method you use, you can determine the desired output.

Comment: 2012-09-20 10:42:31 GMT 
2012-09-20 11:42:31 BST

and file created time = 2012-09-20 12:42:31 (as reported by winscp)